# Segue animation in all four directions

Tags: animation, segue, swipe

i'm looking how to create animations from segue into all 4 directions (up, down, left, right). My aim is to link them to swipes, so that in the direction you swipe the screen moves to the next screenview.

can anyone advise on this? I have been googling a lot and not find a working solution yet.

thanks!